# I cannot change the target .NET Framework in IIS 6

Tags: .net, iis, target-framework

The option to target another version of the .Net Framework is disabled on a particular test system we are using on a current project.

I have tried the following without success:

- Killing all W3WP.EXE processes
- Restarting the IIS service
- Remote Debugging has been removed from the box.

Just hoping for some pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Try re[Registering ASP.NET on IIS](http://community.versionone.com/KnowledgeBase/FAQs/Q10089.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this happens if you install the iis after the .net installation. Just use the aspnet_regiis.exe as explained before.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are asking the right question?

There is no new .NET Runtime version to target. If you have a 3.0 or 3.5 Framework your IIS will still display 2.0 as it's runtime because 3.0 and 3.5 differ only in Framework classes and compiler from a 2.0 application!

You should only see 1.X and 2.0 frameworks in your IIS configuration.

Edit: Target switching only happens when your compile your application. Because 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 all run on the same .NET Runtime Environment 2.0 (VM). 
You still need to have the additional frameworks installed because their API differs, but all run on the same intermediate language instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ASP.net Serveice (Allowed) in IIS

In anyway, you can use some vbscript to change the .net version.